# Entity frame work unable to cast error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

While trying to save data with entity framework I got the following error:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Domain.SubProcessRoot.SubProcess' to type Domain.BalancingRuleRoot.BalancingRule'.

The issue seems to be due to introduction of base class for each entities. In the base class the primary field is declared as `Id`. With the introduction of base class I changed the mapping configuration of each class to point the primary key (`Id` property of base class). If I removed base class from each entity and declared primary key in the respective class itself everything works well. Any Help please. The mapping configuration and entities are:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TId>
{


public TId Id { get; set; }

protected abstract void Validate();
  public override bool Equals(object entity)
    {
        return entity != null
           && entity is EntityBase<TId>
           && this == (EntityBase<TId>)entity;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EntityBase<TId> entity1,
       EntityBase<TId> entity2)
    {
        if ((object)entity1 == null && (object)entity2 == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((object)entity1 == null || (object)entity2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (entity1.Id.ToString() == entity2.Id.ToString())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EntityBase<TId> entity1,
        EntityBase<TId> entity2)
    {
        return (!(entity1 == entity2));
    }


}

    public class MainProcess:EntityBase<int>
    {
        public MainProcess()
        {
            this.MainProcessEmail = new List<MainProcessEmail>();
            this.SubProcess = new List<SubProcess>();
            this.UserAdminRight = new List<UserAdminRight>();
        }

       //public int iMainProcessId { get; set; }
        public string MainProcessname { get; set; }
        public string MainProcessDesc { get; set; }
        public string OwningDept { get; set; }
        public bool EmailAlertEnabled { get; set; }
        public bool FirstChoiceTicketsEnabled { get; set; }
        public int MaxFirstChoiceTicketsPerDay { get; set; }
        public int FirstChoiceQueueId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public bool ActiveInd { get; set; }
        public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
        public virtual FirstChoiceQueue FirstChoiceQueue { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MainProcessEmail> MainProcessEmail { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubProcess> SubProcess { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserAdminRight> UserAdminRight { get; set; }



        protected override void Validate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


public class SubProcess:EntityBase<int>
    {
        public SubProcess()
        {
            this.SubProcessRunInstance = new List<SubProcessRunInstance>();
            this.SubProcessAlertTypeRel = new List<SubProcessAlert>();
            this.BalancingRules = new List<BalancingRule>();
            this.R_SubProcessSetup = new List<SubProcessSetup>();
        }

        //public int SubProcessId { get; set; }
        public string SubProcessName { get; set; }
        public string SubProcessDesc { get; set; }
        public int SignOffTypeId { get; set; }
        public bool FirstChoiceEnabled { get; set; }
        public int MainProcesId { get; set; }
        public bool ActiveInd { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubProcessRunInstance> SubProcessRunInstance { get; set; }
        public virtual MainProcess MainProcess { get; set; }
        public virtual SignOffType SignOffType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubProcessAlert> SubProcessAlertTypeRel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BalancingRule> BalancingRules { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubProcessSetup> R_SubProcessSetup { get; set; }



        protected override void Validate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }



 public partial class BalancingRule:EntityBase<int>
    {
       // public int BalancingRuleId { get; set; }
        public int SubProcessId { get; set; }
        public int BalanceTypeId { get; set; }
        public int BalanceFactorTypeId { get; set; }
        public int BalancingUnitTypeId { get; set; }
        public int BalancingOperatorTypeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MinBalanceFactorValue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MaxBalanceFactorValue { get; set; }
        public string BalanceTypeName { get; set; }
        public bool ActiveInd { get; set; }
        public virtual BalanceFactorType BalanceFactorType { get; set; }
        public virtual BalancingType BalancingType { get; set; }
        public virtual BalancingOperatorType BalancingOperatorType { get; set; }
        public virtual BalancingUnitType BalancingUnitType { get; set; }
        public virtual SubProcess SubProcess { get; set; }



        protected override void Validate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }



     public class MainProcessMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MainProcess>
    {
        public MainProcessMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.MainProcessname)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.MainProcessDesc)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.OwningDept)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("R_MainProcess");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("iMainProcessId");
            this.Property(t => t.MainProcessname).HasColumnName("vcMainProcessname");
            this.Property(t => t.MainProcessDesc).HasColumnName("vcMainProcessDesc");
            this.Property(t => t.OwningDept).HasColumnName("vcOwningDept");
            this.Property(t => t.EmailAlertEnabled).HasColumnName("bEmailAlertEnabled");
            this.Property(t => t.FirstChoiceTicketsEnabled).HasColumnName("bFirstChoiceTicketsEnabled");
            this.Property(t => t.MaxFirstChoiceTicketsPerDay).HasColumnName("iMaxFirstChoiceTicketsPerDay");
            this.Property(t => t.FirstChoiceQueueId).HasColumnName("iFirstChoiceQueueIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.ApplicationId).HasColumnName("iApplicationIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.ActiveInd).HasColumnName("siActiveInd");

            // Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Application)
                .WithMany(t => t.MainProcess)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicationId);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.FirstChoiceQueue)
                .WithMany(t => t.R_MainProcess)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FirstChoiceQueueId);

        }

   public class SubProcessMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SubProcess>
    {
        public SubProcessMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.SubProcessName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.SubProcessDesc)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("R_SubProcess");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("iSubProcessId");
            this.Property(t => t.SubProcessName).HasColumnName("vcSubProcessName");
            this.Property(t => t.SubProcessDesc).HasColumnName("vcSubProcessDesc");
            this.Property(t => t.SignOffTypeId).HasColumnName("iSignOffTypeIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.FirstChoiceEnabled).HasColumnName("bFirstChoiceEnabled");
            this.Property(t => t.MainProcesId).HasColumnName("iMainProcesIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.ActiveInd).HasColumnName("siActiveInd");

            // Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.MainProcess)
                .WithMany(t => t.SubProcess)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MainProcesId);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.SignOffType)
                .WithMany(t => t.R_SubProcess)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SignOffTypeId);

        }
    }


      public class BalancingRuleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BalancingRule>
    {
        public BalancingRuleMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.BalanceTypeName)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("R_SubProcessBalanceFactorTypeRel");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("iSubProcessBalanceFactorTypeRelId");
            this.Property(t => t.SubProcessId).HasColumnName("iSubProcessIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.BalanceTypeId).HasColumnName("iBalanceTypeIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.BalanceFactorTypeId).HasColumnName("iBalanceFactorTypeIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.BalancingUnitTypeId).HasColumnName("iBalancingUnitTypeIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.BalancingOperatorTypeId).HasColumnName("iBalancingOperatorTypeIdFK");
            this.Property(t => t.MinBalanceFactorValue).HasColumnName("dMinBalanceFactorValue");
            this.Property(t => t.MaxBalanceFactorValue).HasColumnName("dMaxBalanceFactorValue");
            this.Property(t => t.BalanceTypeName).HasColumnName("vcBalanceTypeName");
            this.Property(t => t.ActiveInd).HasColumnName("siActiveInd");

            // Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.BalanceFactorType)
                .WithMany(t => t.R_SubProcessBalanceFactorTypeRel)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BalanceFactorTypeId);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.BalancingType)
                .WithMany(t => t.R_SubProcessBalanceFactorTypeRel)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BalanceTypeId);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.BalancingOperatorType)
                .WithMany(t => t.R_SubProcessBalanceFactorTypeRel)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BalancingOperatorTypeId);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.BalancingUnitType)
                .WithMany(t => t.BalancingRules)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BalancingUnitTypeId);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.SubProcess)
                .WithMany(t => t.BalancingRules)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubProcessId);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Found the error. If I remove BaseEntity from BalancingRule class it works. But Can someone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: It turns out that the overloaded Equals() and Operator== is causing the problem. When it is commented it works fine. Can anyone tell me the correct way to implement the overload of equals and operator==